# R: Generate 3 separate folds from a matrix

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm doing cross validation and I want to separate the data into 3 folds. 
I create a matrix with`mat=matrix(sample.int(10, 9*100, TRUE), 6, 10)` which looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10   10    9    3    3    3    4    4    3     9
[2,]    9    3    5    1    3    9    5    5    4     8
[3,]    7    6    6    3    8    2    3   10    7     4
[4,]    7    4   10    8    7    5    2    6    2     8
[5,]    9    7    7    5    3    9    5    8    7     8
[6,]    3    3    1    2    9    3    6    7    6     9
```

I want to get then 3 matrices with the data:

**fold 1**

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]   10   10    9    3    3    3    4    4    3     9
 [2,]    9    3    5    1    3    9    5    5    4     8
```

**fold 2**

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    7    6    6    3    8    2    3   10    7     4
[2,]    7    4   10    8    7    5    2    6    2     8
```

**fold 3**

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    9    7    7    5    3    9    5    8    7     8
[2,]    3    3    1    2    9    3    6    7    6     9
```

Here is my code what I did:

```
require(stats)
mat=matrix(sample.int(10, 9*100, TRUE), 6, 10)
folds=cut(seq(1, nrow(mat)), breaks = 3, labels = FALSE)
#Perform 10 fold cross validation 
for(i in 1:3){
  #segment your data by folds using the which() function 
  testIndexes=which(folds==i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  testData=mat[testIndexes,]
  trainData=mat[-testIndexes,]
}
```

The training data that I get from **fold 1** and **fold 2** are connected, I want to generate them separately. 
This is the generated training set which should be separate in two folds.

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10   10    9    3    3    3    4    4    3     9
[2,]    9    3    5    1    3    9    5    5    4     8
[3,]    7    6    6    3    8    2    3   10    7     4
[4,]    7    4   10    8    7    5    2    6    2     8
```

Comment: `split.data.frame(mat,rep(1:(nrow(mat)/2),each=2))`

Comment: @Onyambu I get an error with this: Error in seq_len(nrow(x)) : 
  argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(nrow(x)) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Comment: Try again. It should be `mat` not `max` Just edited it